# In a gridview do I need to set a imageResource?

Tags: android, image, gridview, adapter, baseadapter

I have a gridview that loads the profile data of users. Below I have the adapter class.

```
public  class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
public static ArrayList<ProfileData>profileData=new ArrayList<>();

public ImageAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return profileData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return profileData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        profileData.add(i,new ProfileData("profile"+i,imageView));
        System.out.println("Image at "+i+"set");
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

}
In my profile data class I use an imageloader to set the images from a response on the server. However, I noticed that in a gridview, all implementations i have seen set the image via         `imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);`
and my implementation is not working so I was wondering if you needed to set an imageResource in the adapter. I set the image using

```
                imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
```

in my imageloader class.

Comment: why you write into your profileData array list in getView()? usually you need only to read data and show it on the device

Answer (score 0):

When you add a item in list then you must be notify to update list array with

```
notifyDataSetChange‌​d();
```

And after add a item you write above line for notify to arraylist updated.